# Убрать мерцание из Picturebox

Tags: c#, bitmap, picturebox

Всем привет возникла такая вот проблема, при перерисовывания изображения возникает сильное мерцание( 2 буферизация на форме включена),прошу помогите , не могу нигде найти решение данной проблемы.

```
 public void OnTimedEvent(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {

        PaintEventArgs p = new PaintEventArgs(pictureBox1.CreateGraphics(), pictureBox1.Bounds); //Компонент на котором нужно рисовать и область на которой нужно рисовать
        Rotate(source, p);
        pictureBox1.Invalidate();
    }
    public void Rotate(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
            Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(img, img.Width, img.Height); // создаем новый битмап   
            e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(bitmap.Width /2 , bitmap.Height + 200); // перемещение в picturebox
            e.Graphics.RotateTransform(Convert.ToInt32(RotationAngle / 1.5)); // угол вращения (Переменная RotationAngle)
            e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(-bitmap.Width/ 2, -bitmap.Height - 200); // задаем точку вокруг которой осуществляется вращение
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(bitmap, bitmap.Width / 6, bitmap.Height / 6);     // проецируем изображение
            bitmap.Dispose();
       }
```

Comment: Может лучше использовать `pictureBox1.Refresh();` вместо `pictureBox1.Invalidate();`?

Comment: @ Rootware тот же результат